# Apache: How to read a variable from command line when apache restarts?

Tags: python, apache, aes, mod-wsgi, virtualhost

Apache: How to read a secret key from command line when apache restarts:

I would like to pass a secret key to a process run by Apache (mod_wsgi).
The key needs to be read from command line while Apache restarts.
And then it needs to be passed to Apache child process as environment variable.
Below is sudo configuration of Apache virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName myserver
    ...        
    SetEnv SECRET_KEY read_from_command_line

    WSGIDaemonProcess myserver processes=1 threads=10
    WSGIProcessGroup myserver
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to read SECRET_KEY from command line while Apache restart?

There will be an external process (CI server) connecting to the Apache server using SSH and doing the restart. I am trying to avoid storing the SECRET_KEy in a file on the Apache server.

Comment: Do you always want to be starting apache manually via the command line? Doesn't seem very feasible in production. Typically you put this in the `defaults` file (or equivalent on your sytem) of the apache user…

Comment: The question is how to store the key not in a plain text file and make it available to Apache child process

Comment: You may be overthinking this. Again, in production you typically want to have something like a watchdog which auto-restarts your server when it goes down, and/or you will want to run software updates which will have to restart the server. It's extremely inconvenient to have to restart it "remotely" just to it can get a configuration variable. It's typical to store these variables in `/etc/default` for the particular user, which is owned by root with 400 permissions. Only someone with root access can see the value.

Comment: Besides, it's more likely that the value will leak from your wsgi programs as part of a log, debug output or other bug, than it would be from the `/etc/default` file.